# form submits before onsubmit function has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm calling the JavaScript function onsubmit of form but form has submit before finished the submit function.If I use the alert in the onsubmit function it finish the function first then submit the form.I used the settimeout function in place of alert but it didn't work.How can I submit the form after the onsubmit has complete.

```
function chat1close(name){
    var abc;
    abc=window.frames[0].test();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'modules/closechat.php?abc='+abc+'&name='+name,
        success:function(data){

        }
    });
    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=" ";
    alert("yes");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're using AJAX you should be preventing the form's native submit action.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code, like where your submit handler is being bound?

Comment: To elaborate on @Diodeus comment: your `onsubmit` handler should `return false;` or use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to cancel the "normal" form submission. But we can't help further without seeing the complete `onsubmit` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `async: false` to your ajax call.  This will prevent it from executing the rest of the function until the call returns.

Comment: No, don't add `async:false`! it freezes the screen.

Comment: @gdoron AFAIK, there's no other way to do this. AJAX is asynchronous, therefore the request is sent, and the rest of the after the `$.post()` is executed.

Comment: @gdoron  If the ajax needs to execute before the form is submitted, he can either add async: false to the call or return false from the initial function and submit the form (and, for that matter, perform any of the rest of this function) from the ajax success handler.

Comment: @JamWaffles - It will work with `async:true`: the submit handler should return false to prevent the default form submit, and then the Ajax success function should submit.

Comment: @user1178695 To resolve that see Guffa's detailed and better-explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

If `chat1close` is the function that is being executed on the form submit and you want the code to be executed `synchronously` then set the following option on the `.ajax` request:

```
async:false,
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The form isn't sent before the function has finished, but you are making an asynchronous AJAX call in the function, and the form is sent before the AJAX response arrives and the success callback function is called.

The only way to do an AJAX call before the form is sent is to use a synchronous AJAX call, but that will freeze the browser while it's waiting for the response:

```
function chat1close(name){
  var abc = window.frames[0].test();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'modules/closechat.php?abc='+abc+'&name='+name,
    success:function(data){
      document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=" ";
      alert("yes");
    }
  });
  return true;
}
```

However, you can stop the form from being sent, and instead send the form after the AJAX response has arrived:

```
function chat1close(name){
  var abc = window.frames[0].test();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    url: 'modules/closechat.php?abc='+abc+'&name='+name,
    success:function(data){
      document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML=" ";
      alert("yes");
      $('#IdOfTheForm')[0].submit();
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is mostly right, except that that calling .submit() again will still return false.  See my example below on how to solve this.

Comment: @RaySuelzer: Good point, I didn't think of that. The jQuery `submit` method is tricky because it triggers the `submit` event, while the DOM `submit` method doesn't. The simple solution is to use the DOM method instead: `$('#IdOfTheForm')[0].submit();`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this:

```
    var $form = jQuery("#the_form");
    var should_submit = false;
    $form.submit(function () {
        if (should_submit)
           return true;

        $.post('some/async/thing', function () {
        //This is an async callback that
        //will set the should submit var to true and resubmit form.
        should_submit = true;
        $form.submit();  //will now submit normally because should_submit is true.
        });
        return false;
    });
```